# Let $A: R\rightarrow S$ and $B:S\rightarrow T$ be two linear transformations. Let $KerB=ImA$. Prove that: $Dim KerA+Dim Im B= Dim R-Dim S+ Dim T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

What I tried to do was name $KerB=ImA$ as $\alpha$. Then I tried to get the left side to appear.

$\left\{\begin{array} DDim R= Dim \alpha+Dim KerA \rightarrow Dim Ker A= Dim R- Dim\alpha\\ Dim S= Dim Im B+Dim\alpha\rightarrow Dim Im B= Dim S- Dim\alpha\end{array}\right.$

$Dim Ker A+Dim Im B= Dim (R)+ Dim (S) - 2 Dim\alpha$

The left side is correct, but that's not the answer and I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you have been asked to prove

> $Dim KerA+Dim Im B= Dim R-Dim S+ Dim T$

cannot be correct. It's not surprising that you weren't able to make your proof work.

Given a situation with vector spaces and linear maps as in your question, you can inflate the dimension of $T$ as much as you want by taking the direct sum of the original $T$ with some other vector space. This lets you make the right hand side of your equation as large as you'd like, or even infinite. However, these new vectors aren't in the image of $B$, so the left hand side of the equation doesn't change. Therefore the two sides don't stay equal.

As a basic example, take $R=S$ and $A$ the identity map, with $B$ the constant zero map. Then any vector space at all works as $T$.